# How to send post ajax request from (.js) file to Spring MVC Controller?

Tags: ajax, spring, post, model-view-controller, controller

(.js)

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                //contentType : "application/json",
                dataType : "json",
                url: "getStateNames",
                //url:"http://localhost:8081/Mining_22_11_17/pages/admin/a.jsp",
                cache: false,               
                data: "region=" + re + "& stId=" + state_id, 
                success: function(response){
                    //$('#result').html("");
                    alert("hiiii state list");
                    var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                    alert("state list" + obj);
                    //$('#result').html("First Name:- " + obj.firstName +"</br>Last Name:- " + obj.lastName  + "</br>Email:- " + obj.email);
                },
                error: function(){                      
                    alert('Error while request..');
                }
            });
```

Spring MVC Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getStateNames",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody RegionDistrict add(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,@RequestParam String region, @RequestParam String stId) {
        System.out.println("Get state");
}
```

By running this program I am getting 404 error.I want to send request using POST only.
[image]

Comment: re and state state_id declared in script

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-refactoring-a-jquery-ajax-post-example/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#yourID").click(function(event) {

    var region   = $('#id').val();
    var state_id = $('#edited').val();


    $.post("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getStateNames", {
        region   : region   ,
        state_id : state_id 
    }, function(data) {

        //var json = JSON.parse(data);
        //...

    }).done(function(data) {
        alert("hiiii state list");
        swal("success");
        //location.reload();
    }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    }).complete(function() {
        //$("#btn-save").prop("disabled", false);

    });
});
```

try this hope its works fine

Comment: $.post("http://localhost:8081/Mining_22_11_17/admin/getStateNames", {
          region   : re  ,
          stId : state_id 
      }, function(data) {
        alert("success");
          //var json = JSON.parse(data);
          //...

      }).done(function(data) {
          alert("hiiii state list");
          swal("success");
          //location.reload();
      }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      }).complete(function() {
          //$("#btn-save").prop("disabled", false);

      });   But still giving 404 error

Comment: ${pageContext.request.contextPath} add this as it is y because it take project path default

Answer (score 0):

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/getStateNames",
    data: { region: re, stId: state_id },
    success : function(response) {
              alert(JSON.stringify(resoinse));
            },
            error: function(){                      
                alert('Error while request..');
            }
});
```

This should work, tell me if this solves your problem